# orchard cms -- How to create import / export for custom non-content data or Simple TableRecord?

Tags: orchardcms-1.9

I have a non-content data in a record class as follows.

```
   public class StudentRecord{
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Number { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name{ get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }        
    }
```

I want to write its export and import. Any idea or just direction will be helpful.

Regards,

I have also reported this question in Orchard Pros: http://orchardpros.net/tickets/9329

Comment: cross posting in not cool

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Repositories to access your data as it is not very performant and breaks the 'Orchard way' of doing things.

you can treat your part as any other part. looking at your model, it does not even seem you might need the record.

A Part is nothing more than a Model with its Entity (DDD) or a wrapper to contain data and logic.

How about just inheriting from ContentPart not ContentPart and access your Object's data with the Infoset methods:  Store, Retrieve. then you can use a Part Driver to just have the Import and Export behaviours in it. 
If you need to query against your part then do inherit from ContentPart where T is your Part Record, still using the Store, Retrieve.

Are you attaching this part to any Content Type? If you give us more context on how this part will be used, you might have a more specific answer. 
How is this part generated? how is it edited?